# How to make multi-line truncation only add ellipsis at the end of a full word?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, webkit

In order to achieve ellipsis truncation at the end of a max-2 line span (ie, text will wrap to a second line and then once its out of space add ellipsis) I'm currently using the "Webkit Flexbox Way" here: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/
If you scroll down to the demos, under the flexbox webkit way, you'll notice that sometimes the ellipsis get placed in the middle of the word. For instance, when I open up the demo, the text truncates the "s" off of "fames" and makes it "fame..." (See attached photo). Instead, I would like fames to be not included at all, since there's not space for the entirety of it, and to instead put the ellipsis on the end of the previous word, in this case malesuada. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?[Example of the problem. "fame..." should not show since the full word is "fames". Ellipsis should be on previous word.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHhJR.png)

Comment: I can tell you right now that this won't be possible with only CSS. If you're open to a JavaScript solution, go ahead and update your question to add that tag.

Comment: I would be interested in a potential js solution, as I have a hard requirement for this @cjl750